# Finding documents based on the minimum value in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

my document structure is something like :

```
    {
        _id: ...,
        key1: ....
        key2: ....
        ....
        min_value: //should be the minimum of all the values in options
        options: [
        {
            source: 'a',
            value: 12,

        },
        {
            source: 'b',
            value: 10,
        },
        ...
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: ...,
        key1: ....
        key2: ....
        ....
        min_value: //should be the minimum of all the values in options
        options: [
        {
            source: 'a',
            value: 24,

        },
        {
            source: 'b',
            value: 36,
        },
        ...
        ]
    }
```

the value of various sources in options will keep getting updated on a frequent basis(evey few mins or hours),
assume the size of options array doesnt change, i.e. no extra elements are added to the list

my queries are of the following type:

-find all documents where the min_value of all the options falls between some limit.

I could first do an unwind on options(and then take min) and then run comparison queries, but I am new to mongo and not sure how performance
is affected by unwind operation. The number of documents of this type would be about a few million.

Or does anyone has any suggestions around changing the document structure which could help me simplify this query? ( apart from creating separate documents per source - it would involves lot of data duplication )
Thanks!

Comment: So what is the actual condition you are looking for? is it the minimum `options.value` less than and greater than a set of numbers for a range? Which MongoDB version do you have? The latest 3.2.x release series has features that alllow this without `$unwind`.

Comment: thanks! are you referring to $elemMatch? and then i use Comparison Query Operators ..something like
        `db.survey.find(
           { options: { $elemMatch: { value: { $gte: 8 }, /*any other filters*/} } }
        )`

Comment: No I was not. Not just anyway. Which MongoDB version do you have?

Comment: i have the latest 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is indeed quite expensive, most notably so with larger arrays, but there is a cost in all cases of usage. There are a couple of way to approach not needing `$unwind` here without real structural changes.

### Pure Aggregation

In the basic case, as of MongoDB 3.2.x release series the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) operator can work directly on an array of values in a "projection" sense in addition to it's standard grouping accumulator role. This means that with the help of the related [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator for processing elements of an array, you  can then get the minimal value without using `$unwind`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Still makes sense to use an index to select only possible documents
    { "$match": {
        "options": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
                "value": { "$gte": minValue, "$lt": maxValue }
            }
        }
    }},

    // Provides a logical filter to remove non-matching documents
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                        "min_value": {
                            "$min": {
                                "$map": {
                                    "input": "$options",
                                    "as": "option",
                                    "in": "$$option.value"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "in": { "$and": [
                        { "$gte": [ "$$min_value", minValue ] },
                        { "$lt": [ "$$min_value", maxValue ] }
                    ]}
                }
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},

    // Optionally return the min_value as a field
    { "$project": {
        "min_value": { 
            "$min": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$options",
                    "as": "option",
                    "in": "$$option.value"
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

The basic case is to get the "minimum" value from the array ( done inside of [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) since we want to use the result "twice" in logical conditions. Helps us not repeat ourselves ) is to first extract the `"value"` data from the `"options"` array. This is done using `$map`.

The output of `$map` is an array with just those values, so this is supplied as the argument to `$min`, which then returns the minimum value for that array.

Using [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) is sort of like a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage with the difference that rather than needing a field to be "present" in the document being examined, you instead just form a logical condition with calculations.

In this case the condition is [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) where "both" the logical forms of [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) and [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) return true against the calculated value ( from `$let` as `"$$min_value"` ).

The `$redact` stage then has the special arguments to apply to `$$KEEP` the document when the condition is `true` or `$$PRUNE` the document from results when it is `false`.

It's all very much like doing `$project` and then `$match` to actually project the value into the document before filtering in another stage, but all done in one stage. Of course you might actually want to `$project` the resulting field in what you return, but it generally cuts the workload if you remove non-matched documents "first" using `$redact` instead.

---

### Updating Documents

Of course I think the **best** option is to actually keep the `"min_value"` field in the document rather than work it out at run-time. So this is a very simple thing to do when adding to or altering array items during update.

For this there is the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/min/) "update" operator. Use it when appending with `$push`:

```js
db.collection.update({
    { "_id": id },
    {
        "$push": { "options": { "source": "a", "value": 9 } },
        "$min": { "min_value": 9 }
    }
})
```

Or when updating a value of an element:

```js
db.collection.update({
    { "_id": id, "options.source": "a" },
    {
        "$set": { "options.$.value": 9 },
        "$min": { "min_value": 9 }
    }
})
```

If the current `"min_value"` in the document is greater than the argument in `$min` or the key does not yet exist then the value given will be written. If it is greater than, the existing value stays in place since it is already the smaller value.

You can even set all your existing data with a simple "bulk" operations update:

```js
var ops = [];

db.collection.find({ "min_value": { "$exists": false } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    // Queue operations
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
           "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
           "update": {
               "$min": {
                   "min_value": Math.min.apply(
                       null,
                       doc.options.map(function(option) {
                           return option.value
                       })
                   )
               }
           }
        }
    });

    // Write once in 1000 documents
    if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
});

// Clear any remaining operations
if ( ops.length > 0 )
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Then with a field in place, it is just a simple range selection:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "min_value": {
        "$gte": minValue, "$lt": maxValue
    }
})
```

So it really should be in your best interests to keep a field ( or fields if you regularly need different conditions ) in the document since that provides the most efficient query.

Of course, the new functions of aggregation `$min` along with `$map` also make this viable to use without a field, if you prefer more dynamic conditions.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. learnt quite a few new things!